# Replace word with a blank space in comma separated files

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have some files in a directory where I want to remove a specific word and replace it with an empty string (`""`).

The files contain `20c` in the filename to show *20th March* (`a` is January, `b` is February, etc.). How can I make sure only files that have `20c` `21c` and `22c` in the filename get the specific word removed? The word always exists in the 6th field (column 6).

Comment: This question is a bit unclear.  Do you want to distinguish at the command line or in the script?  And for that matter how are you doing the replace?

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in ./*2[0-2]c*; do perl -i -pe 's/^[^,]*,{5}\KYOUR_SPECIFIC_WORD_ONLY//' "$f" ; done
```